Join with a condition between two values
I have two tables [sales] and [payments] and I want to see if a payment is made between the sale's product start date and the end date of the sale BUT sometimes the product hasn't started yet!
Sales Table



Customer
Sale_Date
Product_Start
Product_End




ABC---
20240801
20240801-----
20240831---


DEF---
20240801
000000  -----
000000  ---



Payment Table



Customer
Payment_Date




ABC---
20240815----



 SELECT S.*, nvl(P.Payment_Date,000000)
 FROM sales s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments p
  ON p.Payment_Date BETWEEN
    CASE WHEN Product_Start > 000000
           THEN Product_Start AND Product_End
       WHEN Product_Start = 000000
           THEN 29991201 AND 29991231
    END

-- I.E. Sometime in the future so it is impossible to pick up a payment as the product hasn't started
Expected Results:



Customer
Sale_Date
Product_Start
Product_End
Payment_Date




ABC---
20240801
20240801-----
20240831---
20240815----


DEF---
20240801
000000  -----
000000 ----
000000 -----



above gives me an error saying missing keyword and highlights the AND on row 6
I tried adding in something after the END eg END = 1 but same error

On a side note: You are storing dates as numbers or strings??? You shouldn't. Store dates as DATEs.

The output of a case expression (the bit in the THEN or ELSE clause) needs to be a scalar value. You, instead just have Product_Start AND Product_End which is sort of nonsense to the case expression logic.
Instead, as an option, you can use two case expressions to handle the output of two values:
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments p
  ON p.Payment_Date BETWEEN
    CASE WHEN Product_Start > 000000
           THEN Product_Start 
       WHEN Product_Start = 000000
           THEN 29991201 
    END
    AND
    CASE WHEN Product_Start > 000000
           THEN Product_End 
       WHEN Product_Start = 000000
           THEN 29991231
    END

This way your code looks something like JOIN table ON table.col BETWEEN <case expression1> AND <case expression2>

A CASE expression results in a single value. Product_Start AND Product_End is not a single value (that would only be the case, if Product_Start and Product_End were both BOOLEAN columns).
We usually don't use CASE  expressions in the WHERE clause, because a CASE expression is used to create a value depending on boolean conditions. So why create a value from boolean expressions in order to use it in another boolean expression instead of working with the original boolean expressions right away?
SELECT S.*, NVL(p.payment_date, 0)
FROM sales s
LEFT OUTER JOIN payments p
  ON (s.product_start > 0 AND p.payment_date BETWEEN s.product_start and s.product_end)
  OR (s.product_start = 0 AND p.payment_date BETWEEN THEN 29991201 AND 29991231)


OR operators in join clauses frequently cause performance issues. The optimizer may rewrite with OR-expansion as two UNION'd queries each with a different join clause, but at sometimes it won't and you'll be looking at a mandatory nested loops join. Given that the only join condition here is an inequality, OP probably has no choice - this will certainly use nested loops, but in many other situations you wouldn't want to disqualify hash joins by using an OR.

The simplest is simply to use a DECODE or CASE separately around each operand of BETWEEN. For something simple like this, DECODE is more compact and easier to read when aligned vertically:
SELECT S.*, nvl(P.Payment_Date,0)
 FROM sales s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments p
  ON p.Payment_Date BETWEEN DECODE(product_start,0,29991201,product_start) AND 
                            DECODE(product_start,0,29991231,product_end)

By the way, those numbers look like dates in YYYYMMDD format. You'd be better off storing real dates and using real dates in your logic rather than numbers. But the same technique would apply.
